# titanium making maps in my app to locate some places. Giveing a lot of errors

Tags: android, api, titanium, maps

I'm making an app and i need google maps inside it. It needs to highlight some spots and i found this code:

```
var MapModule = require('ti.map');
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
var mountainView = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED
});
var mapview = MapModule.createView({
    mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView]
});
win.add(mapview);
win.open();
```

but it is giving me a lot of errors:

```
http://pastebin.com/kDwAsZWh
```

i have added the api key, also added ti.map to my TiApp. Can anyone help me out? :/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you try this code? Your problem is **Google Play Services**.

You need an emulator or device with this services installed.

At **AVD Manager**, you must use Targets with Google APIs prefix, for example (emulator 4.4.2):

Google APIs (x86 System Image)(Google Inc.) - API Level 19.

Also, at tiapp.xml you need add this permissions with your API key:

```
<manifest android:versionName="1.0.0">
...
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_APP_ID.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<application>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4452000"/>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
</application>
...
</manifest>
```

In theory, any phisical device can use Google Maps.